# The Norwegian Foreman

Tags: wordplay

An American architect was in Norway for a business trip, and he was working with a Norwegian Foreman who was building a skyscraper. The Norwegian did not know how to *say* any numbers in English, but he did know a few English words which he used to communicate his thoughts to the architect. In one case, the American pointed to a wall on his blueprint: "What's the length of the wall in feet?" he asked. The Foreman drew three pictures next to one another:

- The first was of a pile of dirt
- The second was a large Maple tree
- The third was of a squating dog which was defecating.

***What was the length of the wall (excluding units)?***

Hint:

> When the Norwegian was explaining the defecating dog, he didn't seem to be pointing at the dog

My apologies for the many edits, this is my first post here. I swear I'll be more straightforward next time!

Comment: I was thinking something like "thirty-three feet" = "dirty tree feces", but then I remembered you said he didn't know any English numbers.

Comment: So... is my answer *right*? You seem to have made a lot of clarifying edits in that direction...

Comment: almost, but not quite :)

Comment: What about "smelly tree feces"? (Twenty three feet)

Comment: @OP Please reply; Not a full answer but by any chance is maple tree "43"? (Maple sounds like April, the 4th month and tree sounds like 3)

Comment: @schil227 updated my answer after your edit...

Comment: @FlorianF: The exact same question I have raised in my answerm :Note: I still doubt, if the foreman can made up words to sound like/similar to the number(number representing the height of wall), why can't he just say it loud?? Is he mute/the architect deaf and the foreman doesn't know how to write in English??:

Comment: Not to mention that I'm pretty sure numerals are the same in Norwegian as in English...

Comment: I told this puzzle to a Norwegian, who got the intended answer straight away! Ergo: this is a good puzzle ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wall was

> 33 1/3 units long.

This is because

> Dirt -> Thirt(y)
>  Tree -> Three
>  dog poop = turd > third

So it was

> Dirt, a tree, and a turd.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is;

> 30, 43.2 ft

Or in words;

> Thirty-hundred, forty-three, dot two.

Or in ***OTHER*** words;

> Three-thousand, forty-three, decimal two. (3043.2)

How I got it:

> Thirty;
>
>  Dirty (pile of dirt) sounds like 30
>
>  Forty-three;
>
>  Maple (sounds like April, the 4th month of the year) tree (sounds like 3)
>
>  Dot two;
>
>  Dog poo, need I say anything else?

Credit to AeJay for;

> The "dog" in dog poo meaning "dot"

Comment: Nice interpretation, but that wall is simply too long :)

Comment: Well it *is* a skyscraper lol. +1 for creativity?

Answer (score 0):

I think the height of the wall is

> **33.4**

The foreman may have used "The first was of a pile of dirt"

> instead of **thirty**

The second was a large Maple tree

> to represent **three**

and The third was of a squatting dog which was defecating

> is dog poo and it can be interpreted as dot four(.4)

Combining all these we get

> **dirty tree dog poo >> thirty three dot four (33.4)**

---

### New Edits

From OP's comment on another answer ("It's a measurement of length, not area") I think he is looking for the area, not length.

So The last point "a squatting dog which was defecating" may be referring to

> square feets (squat feces) [Since he is not English, he may be thinking as feets instead of feet]

So the final answers become

> **33 Sq.ft. (Thirty Three Square Feet)**

***Note: I still doubt, if the foreman can made up words to sound like/similar to the number(number representing the height of wall), why can't he just say it loud?? Is he mute/the architect deaf and the foreman doesn't know how to write in English??***

Comment: Quote: "God poo" LOL.

Comment: Sorry. It was a type. Yet a funny mistake. :P

Comment: You mean typo? Yes, I know. string.reverse("dog") == "god"

Comment: I'll give you a +1, and you'll see why when someone finds the right answer

Comment: nope, it's a measurement in feet; just looking for a number here (will update question)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is

> Just 33 feet

Pile of dirt

> Dirty => Thirty

Maple Tree

> Tree =>Three

a dog defecating

> shit => feet?

Comment: 33 Feet feet? It's a measurement of length, not area!

Comment: @schil227 well when someone asks "What's the length of the wall in feet?" I would reply "Some number feet"

Comment: @downvoter care to elaborate?

Comment: I'm guessing it was every user that swore in their answer, which I don't agree with (a riddle's a riddle, ya know?)